# Google Cloud ML Model Version creation error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I m trying to deploy a simple model on Google Cloud ML which has been built using tensorflow and keras. Here is my modelling code

```
from keras.optimizers import adam
# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=14, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
opt = adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

I have also created a custom prediction file

%%writefile model_prediction.py

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np


class CustomModelPrediction(object):

    def __init__(self, model, processor):
        self._model = model
        self._processor = processor

    def _postprocess(self, predictions):
        labels = ['lbl1', 'lbl2']
        return [
            {
                "label":labels[int(np.round(prediction))],
                "score":float(np.round(prediction,4))
            } for prediction in predictions]

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        preprocessed_data = np.array(self._processor.transform(instances))
        predictions =  self._model.predict(preprocessed_data)
        labels = self._postprocess(predictions)
        return labels

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        import tensorflow.keras as keras
        model = keras.models.load_model(
            os.path.join(model_dir,'keras_saved_model.h5'))
        with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'processor_state.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            processor = pickle.load(f)
        return cls(model, processor)
```

Setting these parameter

```
MODEL_NAME='keras_test'
VERSION_NAME='v1'
RUNTIME_VERSION='1.13'
REGION='europe-west1'
```

When I try to create a version

```
!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} \
--model {MODEL_NAME} \
--origin gs://{BUCKET}/{MODEL_DIR} \
--python-version 3.5 \
--runtime-version {RUNTIME_VERSION} \
--package-uris gs://{BUCKET}/{PACKAGES_DIR}/classifier_test-0.1.tar.gz \
--prediction-class=model_prediction.CustomModelPrediction
```

I get the following error

```
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: learning_rate (Error code: 0)
```

However the prediction class seems to be working perfectly on my local machine.

Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you possibly mixing imports from tf and keras as you mention this is a tensorflow model... what happens if you use tf.keras.optimizers.Adam

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the issue, how are you saving your model, using keras or tf.keras? Also, what versions are you using in your local environment?

Comment: So my model is  `model = tf.keras.models.Model(model_input, model_output)`. Also doing `!sudo pip install keras --upgrade` resolved this error. But it starts giving new error : `Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.                  
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['ragged'])) (Error code: 0)"`

Comment: also @PaddyPopeye You can try replicating this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/tensorflow/custom-prediction-routine-keras.ipynb. I found the issue happening here as well

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33479

Comment: what is the version of tf you are using